# Sync certain contacts between two devices/google account

Tags: contacts, sync, google-contacts

Is there any way of syncing selected contacts from one android device/google account to another?

Consider the following example:
Person A  and Person B share real life contacts, but on their smartphones, each person has to maintain contact details on their own. The data is there, so why do not share this?

The following ideas came to my mind:

1. Create a new, shared account. All contacts that should be shared are stored in this account. On each smartphone, contact syncing for this account is enabled. This should work just fine on android smartphones. **But the contacts of the shared account are not accessible through the web interfaces of the individual accounts!**
2. Use [Gmail Shared Contacts for Google Apps](http://www.gmailsharedcontacts.com/). The drawback here is, that **this does not work for generic `@gmail.com` addresses**.

Is there any other way (android app, software for Windows/Ubuntu, own contact server, ...) to sync common contacts in a way, that the contacts are present both on android devices and through the normal google webpages?

Comment: I asked [a very similar question over at Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/is-there-a-way-to-share-synchronize-contacts-between-google-accounts). The long and short of it is: No, not really. _Some_ third-party services might be helpful.

Comment: The approach at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60825/transfer-contacts-from-android-to-google-contacts could be used to copy contacts from one to the other and back. But alas, it doesn't automagically keep them synchronized.