# Transfer contacts from android to google contacts

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s, sync, data-transfer, google-contacts

I have a Google account, and my android is a Galaxy S. I want to transfer all my contacts from my cellphone into Google contacts. If you use the phones syncing option by default, it is a one way sync from Google contacts to your phone. I have also tried CardDav, which I downloaded from the play store. It does the same time, it just syncs from Google, to your phone.

Can some one please tell me how I can sync all the contacts from my android to my Google contacts?

Comment: How are they stored? On SIM? Or as "phone contacts"? What Android version? Have you tried if you can "import" them via the contacts app (should work at least for SIM contacts)? After that, the "normal" contact sync should pick them up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tested this on my phone and my gmail, and it seems to work. I'm running 4.4 with the stock Contacts app on my phone.

1. On your phone, in the Contacts app: menu button -> import/export contacts
2. Choose export to storage and it will create a .vcf file to /storage/emulated/0/ which is the root folder for storage
3. Transfer this file via email, or usb to a computer where you are logged into gmail
4. In Gmail, go to your contacts by clicking on the little down arrow by GMail on the top left
5. Slightly to the right is a More button with a down arrow, click on it
6. Choose import, and select the .vcf file

:)

Comment: This seems like a perfectly reasonable solution. It's also straightforward and fairly easy to understand. I *like* this new guy.

Comment: Dawww shucks. Long time lurker, first time poster. :)

Comment: Hmmm... This didn't work for me. The last step produces no visible response. The import window just goes away. I do have 5000 contacts in a 30 Mb .vcf file. Could there be an issue there?

Comment: I get as far as exporting contacts, the file name shows up then disappears never to be seen again. I thought I could email it to myself, and import the contacts into Google. I had hoped. :( Where did the file go??

Comment: @TimothyChilds usually to your SD card, and most times it's named `0001.vcf`. Generally spoken: watch out for `.vcf` files on your SD card; the one you just created should have a current time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

On my phone, a LG L70, running Android 4.4 it is possible to export contacts to the phone like above comment.

But after that you can also import contacts from the phone storage (via Contacts --> Menu button --> import contacts). So you can import the .vcf file from the phone storage to your Google account. There is no need for a desktop computer to be involved.

Answer (score 0):

From my Galaxy S4 experice:
Careful because contacts filed in your Samsung Account will not be uploaded to your Google contacts via sync.

Also, when you use the export function, only those contacts saved on your device are transferred (i.e. Samsung and Google contacts are not exported).

The only way of moving all the contacts is via the "Share namecard via". In you settings you can choose to send all the contacts in a single file. So you can send a .vcf file to your email, save it locally and then export this file to Google.

Once you are happy that all your contacts are safely stored in Google, just delete all your contacts from your mobile (I disabled google sync first just to be on the safe side) and then re-sync with Google. All your contacts should now flow from google to your device.

Also, dont waste your time with Kies. It's rubbish

Disclaimer: always backup contacts between steps just to be on the safe side. Also check your backup to ensure that all addresses, emails and numbers are being saved without losses.  Deleting all your contacts can result in loss of data, so make sure you have backups to revert to if the above doesnt work